# How to render two html files separately in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have been trying to make Flask render two templates at once so that one template can play some video, and the other template, which will be next to it, stream some type of content, meaning it updates every few seconds. When I had only one template, I was able to update it, but the problem was even the video kept restarting. How can I fix this problem? If my two template concept is flawed and impossible, is it possible to get the same results with something else such as reloading only specific divs in the web page.

Note: This is all on one page.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, flask only renders 1 template.

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask only renders 1 template. Yes, you could use iframes to reload only some parts of your website but they are considered a bad practice. Probably the best option is to use AJAX to pool the server for updates periodicaly without reloading the page. You could use jQuery to do it manualy or find some front-end library to make your life easier.